# Find an element using jquery with a kind of regex comparison in the data-title?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a div with class `textbox` and also has a data-title that starts with the string in the variable `dt`. 
Something like this:

```
var $theboxes = $(".textbox[data-title^="+dt+"]");
```

I've tried this but it causes an error in jquery. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What error does it cause?  It seems to work for me, so what is the value of `dt`?  What is your HTML?

Comment: If only `jQuery.hasData()` worked like we all wished. `$('.textbox').hasData()` would be awesome. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually need to quote the attribute value.
Try something like this:

```
var $theboxes = $(".textbox[data-title^='"+dt+"']");
```