# jquery not finding elements with dynamic data-title

Tags: jquery, html, find, arabic

I'm still trying to [Find-an-element-using-jquery-with-a-kind-of-regex-comparison-in-the-data-title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894719/find-an-element-using-jquery-with-a-kind-of-regex-comparison-in-the-data-title#comment19143642_13894719), where I have `div`s of class `.textbox` and a dynamically generated data title. So I wanted to find the boxes with that specific data title, and this was the suggested code, which brought no errors:

```
var $theboxes = $(".textbox[data-title^='"+dt+"']");
```

However, it doesn't seem to actually find any `.textbox`, even though they do exist. Because whenever I try `$theboxes.length`, it's always `0`.

This is an example of a data title, by the way: `en_Person_Title/ لقب`. So that's English before the slash, Arabic after it. And I have more than one textboxes with this same data-title attribute, but the code isn't finding any of them. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Try the `contains attribute *`  i.e, `[data-title*=`

Comment: Also first check if this is returning anything `$(".textbox[data-title]").length`

Comment: It does return the right number of textboxes with data titles otherwise. I tried `*=` but no diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I tried *= but no diff. "

`^=` searches for Starts With....and it is **case sensitive**.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnQnV/1/

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this though. My `dt`s are exactly the same. I was wondering if the problem is related to comparing strings including non-English UTF-8 characters or something?

Answer (score 1):

When you select elements with jquery, it only selects elements that exist when that code is ran. If you dynamically add more elements or modify elements so that they would be selectable by that selector, you need to re-select them.

```
var $theboxes = $(".textbox[data-title^='"+dt+"']");
console.log($theboxes.length); // 0

$(".textbox:not([data-title])").first().attr("data-title",dt+"foobar");
console.log($theboxes.length); // 0

$theboxes = $(".textbox[data-title^='"+dt+"']");
console.log($theboxes.length); // 1
```